# For what values does my dynamical system produce periodic orbits?

Tags: dynamical-systems

For what values of $a$ does the function, $f$, contain periodic orbits, where $f$ is given by:
$$f(x)=a+x \mod 1.$$
It seems for any rational number $a$ you get periodic orbits although I don't know how to prove that. Does anyone know if you get periodic orbits if $a$ is irrational? I don't really know anything about dynamical systems so help in approaching this problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f^{n}(x) = n a + x \mod 1$, where $f^{n}$ is $f$ iterated $n$ times.  This is $x$ if and only if $n a$ is an integer, so $a$ is an integer divided by $n$, i.e. a rational number.

Comment: Does that mean that the set: $$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\left\{x,f(x),f^2(x),...,f^k(x)\right\}$$ is the real number line, [0,1], if $a$ is irrational?

Comment: It doesn't **mean** that, but it's true.

Comment: How could we show that it's true if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: E.g. it follows from the  [equidistribution theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem).

Comment: But if: $$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\left\{x_0,f(x_0),f^2(x_0),...,f^k(x_0)\right\}=[0,1],$$ then wouldn't that make the set $[0,1]$ a countable infinite set so it cannot be true?

Comment: @Peanutlex I'm taking $\lim$ in the sense that every point of $[0,1]$ is a limit point of members of the sequence $f^k(x_0)$, not that every point of $[0,1]$ is actually in the sequence.